# i can't import my custom framework in my view controller

Tags: xcode, frameworks

i developed a framework and it works fine on both architecture for Device and Simulator but when i drag it into my Xcode Project i can't import it or even can't access it's header files.. is this trick! Any Help?

Comment: You should describe precisely _how_ you added the framework into your project. Also describe the errors that the compiler issues. Usually, there's no problem adding frameworks to projects and it is described in the documentation how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out , it was syntax error in the script which builds the framework for architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64, x86, etc).

i fixed it within this tutorial  http://www.insert.io/frameworkios8xcode6/